# Proof of an inequality in arithmetic, geometric and harmonic means

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $$\left[\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}\right]^{x+y+z}\gt x^xy^yz^z\gt \left[\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right]^{x+y+z}$$

I could prove the inequality between the first two terms using the fact that $A.M\gt G.M$ in the following way. $$\left[\frac{x(\frac{x^2}{x})+y(\frac{y^2}{y})+z(\frac{z^2}{z})}{x+y+z}\right]\gt (x^xy^yz^z)^{\frac{1}{x+y+z}}$$

But I am unable to prove the inequality between the next two terms.

Comment: If you know weighted A.M. $\geq$ G.M. $\geq$ H.M. inequality (arithmetic mean, geometric mean, and harmonic mean respectively), the second part just follows from weighted G.M. H.M, applied to the exact same weights and variables. These are special cases of the more general [weighted power mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean)

Comment: I am not aware of that. Is there any other way of proving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to spell out what Ivan says:
Consider the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3 = x, y, z$ and weights $w_1,w_2,w_3 = x/s, y/s, z/s$, where $s  = x+y+z$. The inequality between harmonic and geometric (weighted) mean says that:
$$ \prod_{i} a_i^{w_i} \geq \frac{1}{\sum_i w_i \frac{1}{a_i}}.$$ 
Thus:
$$ x^{x/s}y^{y/s}z^{z/s} \geq \frac{1}{\frac{x}{s} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{y}{s} \frac{1}{y}+ \frac{z}{s} \frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{3 \cdot{1}{s} }= \frac{s}{3}.$$
Rising both sides to power $ s $ gives the claim:
$$ x^x y^y z^z \geq \left( \frac{x+y+z}{3} \right)^{x+y+z}.$$